# Laptop battery worn 9% in two months, is it normal?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

I just got a new laptop which is just 2 months old running Windows 10. Today when I checked the battery life the battery has worn down 9% which is like 4.5% per month, in this rate my battery would only last close to two years or less.

What's the average wear rate of the laptop battery? I use the laptop plugged in most of the time how ever let it drain (not completely) and charge it back once in a week. So a 9% drop is like 50 charging cycles which it definitely didn't had.

So this much of wearing is normal or too much? average wear rate of the laptop battery?

Of course this is assuming that the battery was 100% by the time I bought it, being a brand new laptop I assume that it should be close to 100%.

[image]

Comment: Those estimates are pretty crude.  Displaying it to 1/10th of 1% precision is a joke.  I suspect that you will see a lot of variation in the estimate.

Comment: Why are you letting the battery go down to nothing?  Is it because you're familiar with common recommendations for NiCad, which may not apply to Lith-ion?  My new laptop tends to aim for 60% capacity and then stop charging; I could fill capacity if I expected it be without electricity and wanted it to function as long as possible before being drained.  But apparently with this new battery, leaving it charged (but not fully charged) reduces the overall threat that wear and tear inflict upon longevity over time.

Comment: @TOOGAM no buddy I don't drain it to 0. Once a week I drain it till about 40% and charge it back :) Unfortunately I can't set a charging limit to my laptop, that option is not available in bios. Wish it would :)

Comment: For my Lenovo laptop, it is Windows driver, presumably using a Windows driver, not a BIOS option (that I've noticed)

Answer (score 1):

The wear level that is given here is really never accurate. You may find it to fluctuate often, sometimes even decrease. Measuring battery wear level is a real tough job, since there are not many accurate parameter you can get.

Anyways, you shouldn't expect more than three years of good battery backup from a laptop. Depending on your use, this may vary, but two and a half to three years on, you probably would have a fourth of the battery backup you get now.

Answer (score 0):

A lithium XXXX battery should last at least 300 charge/discharge cycles - realistically many more -  so either the software is lying to you (likely) or the battery is a dud.